# The condition style on measure field of crosstab is not working

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I have a problem with *JasperReport*'s crosstab.

I want to add style on measure field, but it doesn't work. Is it possible to do that or not?

The style in first column works fine.

I used this style:

```
<style name="proba" mode="Opaque">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{BR_kupaca}< 5.0 ]]></conditionExpression>
        <style mode="Opaque" forecolor="#FF0000" backcolor="#CCFFCC">
            <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#FF0000"/>
        </style>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

on field in designer that is represent of measure: BR_kupaca, in style I put that style proba. But nothing happened - my values are always black.

I want to be colored in red every value that is less then 5

[image: crosstab style problem]

Comment: Could you post the expression for style

Comment: The styles are work well in crosstabs. Something wrong with your template

Comment: <style name="proba" mode="Opaque">
  <conditionalStyle>
   <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{BR_kupaca}< 5.0 ]]></conditionExpression>
   <style mode="Opaque" forecolor="#FF0000" backcolor="#CCFFCC">
    <pen lineWidth="0.25" lineColor="#FF0000"/>
   </style>
  </conditionalStyle>
 </style>

Comment: Style works fine in first column...see first column, values 2 and 4 are with style...I create a new style with variable br_kupaca...on measures...and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens most likely because your crosstab cell contains a textField for which the forecolor was specifically set to black(#000000).

When a style attribute(forecolor, backcolor, font name/size, etc) is set directly on an element, it takes precedence over the value that is inherited from a specified style.

So what you need to do is to find the textField to which you have applied the "proba" style:

`<textField><reportElement style="proba" .... />...</textField>`

and remove the `forecolor` attribute inside the `reportElement`.

Comment: Thanks.that field was text field, I change measure to integer, then  delete that field from designer, and add it again, and my style start to work!  silly me!

Answer (score 0):

Another reason could be (for others with basically the same problem regarding the **`Backcolor`** - like us) the **`Transparent`** value of the `Text field` that may be set to "nothing" (`<Inherited>`) and inherits `true` instead of **`false`**.
Setting it directly to `false` is the straight forward solution.